# SFDX: CantFindCredentialProgram message: Cant find required security software /usr/bin/secret-tool

Tags: salesforcedx, pipelines

I am facing the below issue with SFDX bitbucket pipelines: I could not find it in anywhere in the google related to this issue.

However, the JWT authentication is success as I can see it in the log.

[image]

[image]

**ERROR:
An error occurred authorizing this org. name: CantFindCredentialProgram message: Cant find required security software /usr/bin/secret-tool**

Answer (score 2):

Wade Wegner helped me to resolve this issue. I had to install SFDX before JWT grant

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=false
          - export SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN=true
          - export SFDX_DOMAIN_RETRY=300
          - export SFDX_DISABLE_APP_HUB=true
          - export SFDX_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
          - mkdir sfdx
          - wget -qO- https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1
          - "./sfdx/install"
          - export PATH=./sfdx/$(pwd):$PATH
          - sfdx --version
          - "sfdx plugins --core"         
          - sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i $CLIENT_ID -f jwt/server.key -u $DEVHUB_USERNAME --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias DevHub   
          - sfdx force:org:list
```